# Vue TinyMCE not working inside a web component parent?

Tags: vue.js, tinymce, web-component

I just converted my small Vue project to Web Component using.
After that the TinyMCE is not working properly. All features are disabled.
It works fine if I switch back to Vue Component.

[All features disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU2c7.png)

Have anyone experienced this?
And how to get it working?

Comment: It's unknown what your case looks like and what could go wrong, but it's possible it's shadow dom to blame.

Comment: "not working" is a too vague to provide an answer. Are there any errors being thrown in the console? Could you provide more details, or a minimal reproduction?